# Dimension of $\text{Sym}^2(V)$ and $\text{Alt}^2(V)$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, terminology

Is there something what we can say about the dimensions of $$\text{Sym}^2(V)=\text{span}\{x\otimes y+y\otimes x| x,y\in V\}$$ and $$\text{Alt}^2(V)=\text{span}\{x\otimes y-y\otimes x| x,y\in V\}?$$

Since these are subspaces of $V\otimes V$ the dimension must be less or equal to $n^2$, where $n$ is the dimension of $V$.

My aim is to show this with a dimension argument via the dimension formula, that $\text{Sym}^2(V)\cap\text{Alt}^2(V)=0$. Maybe this is possible with an other argument as well.

Comment: Yes, they have dimensions $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ and $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$. You do not need to know this to solve your other problem.

Comment: Alright, thank you. With this information I can easily solve my other probme. But since you say that this is possible without this information: How would you show this trivial intersection part?

Comment: Just write up what it would mean for an element to be in the intersection.

Answer (score 0):

This is only valid when the characteristic of the field is not $2$.

Consider the map $\Phi:V\otimes V\to V\otimes V$ defined
by $a\otimes b\mapsto b\otimes a$. Then $\Phi^2$ is the identity,
and $\text{Sym}^2(V)$ and $\text{Alt}^2(V)$ are the $+1$ and $-1$
eigenspaces of $\Phi$. Then $V\otimes V$ is the direct sum of
these eigenspaces.

All of this assumes that we are not
in characteristic $2$.